# DM multipath along with local disk

Tags: linux, lvm, multipath

I have one /storage partition which is created from /dev/sdc local disk which is in LVM, now i want to extend it. we have 1 disk free which is a multipath disk over iscsi.
can i add this disk in the existing LVM? will there be any issue when server reboots?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> can i add this disk in the existing LVM?

Yes, you can add it as PV (`pvcreate`) to an existing VG (`vgextend`).

> will there be any issue when server reboots?

Normaly no. Multipath is initialized before LVM. But if you have the root LV on the VG that has the PV on iSCSI/multipath, you need to add iscsi and multipath to initramfs.

Ubuntu:

```
touch /etc/iscsi/iscsi.initramfs
update-initramfs -u
```

CentOS/RHEL:

```
echo "iscsi" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
mkinitrd -f $(uname -r)
```

Comment: its a separate VG. you need to add iscsi and multipath to initramfs ---> you mean rebuild initrmafs? Thank you.

Comment: I mean adding iscsi kernel module to initramfs. I added instructions how to do this. Make sure you backup /boot/ and /etc/ before doing any changes.